# How to run hdparm at startup so that it sets apm to 254?

Tags: windows-7, hdparm

I downloaded hdparm from here: https://sites.google.com/site/disablehddapm/ and so far it's been great, it successfully stopped rapid increase in load/unload cycle count. The only problem is that I have to rerun it manually every time I boot up Windows 7. Is there a way to run hdparm automatically while windows starts?

Answer (score 0):

Copy the executable/copy shortcut to the executable to start menu -> all programs -> startup.

Answer (score -1):

I moved hdparm location from Program Files(x86) to Program Files and now it runs automatically at start up after I log in.

[image]